# Common reasons for OpenGL Textures not being rendered

Tags: android, textures, rendering, opengl-es-2.0

I just heard from a user who says that my (Android OpenGL ES 2.0) app (a game) won't run on his HTC 1X+ handset.  All he gets is the music and the banner ad at the top of the screen and nothing else.

Unfortunately I don't have an HTC 1X+ to test this on.

Some notes:

- Although my textures are not power of 2, I'm only using GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
- From what I've read, the HTC 1X+ has a max Texture Size of [2048 x 2048](http://gfxbench.com/device.jsp?benchmark=gfx30&os=Android&api=gl&D=HTC%20One%20X%2B%20%28Endeavor%20C2%2C%20Evitare%20UL%2C%20EVARE_UL%20-%20Tegra%203%29&testgroup=info) and it gets it's resources from the [XHDPI](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/) folder (annoyingly), even so, I have only 1 texure that exceeds that size, all other objects displayed on my app's opening page use textures much smaller than this max amount, so something should be displayed.
- I'm not using texture compression of any kind

My app runs quite happily on the 15 (aprox) other devices I, and others have tested it on - just the 1x (so far) is giving problems.

Can anyone point out some **common issues** with OpenGL ES 2.0 that could be causing these textures not to be rendered?  Are there any quirks with certain Android versions or devices?

I haven't yet posted any code simply because the app works on most devices, and I'm not sure which parts of the code would be helpful, but if any code is required, please just ask.

**Edit - including texture loading code**

```
 public static int LoadTexture(GLSurfaceView view, Bitmap imgTex){

    //Array for texture
    int textures[] = new int[1];
    try {
        //texture name
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        //Bind textures
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        //Set parameters for texture
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

        //Apply texture
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, imgTex, 0);

        //clamp texture
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    } catch (Exception e){

    }
    //Increase texture count
    textureCount++;
    //Return texture
    return textures[0];
}
```

Comment: And you have `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` set to `GL_LINEAR` or `GL_NEAREST` for textures that don't have mipmaps?

Comment: Hi @RetoKoradi, I have the following in my code: GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

Comment: I've added the code I use to apply textures @RetoKoradi, hope it will help you spot and problems - thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Have you checked the sampler properties?
  The settings look correct, but why not also specify the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S setting? Use GLES20.glTexParameteri for integer values.
- What type of bitmap are you using?
  Try to force the internal format to GL_RGBA, GL_BGR, GL_RGB
- Do you properly unbind or bind to a different texture?
  Other texture settings may be causing havoc in other parts of the code..
- Do you specify the correct texture unit in your shader? 
  Print out the shader's sampler attribute position so you know this is correct, and make sure to bind the texture to it explicitly during rendering.

Comment: Thanks @StarShine, interestingly, I just tried adding the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S setting but then some of my textures display OK, some display as black and some don't display at all (or 'fully transparent').

Comment: Regarding the other points, if any of these were wrong, would it be expected that these would run on 90% of devices but break on one ot two specific ones? Also, can you confirm that **all** openGL ES 2.0 devices support NPOT textures (when using clamp_to_edge and non-mipmaps)?  Because my textures are NPOT but I'm using the modes that should be supported so I want to rule that out as being the issue....

Comment: We've had texture problems at some point, and it was due to the sampler properties not setup, apart from the usual bugs like faulty pointers etc.. We also had rendering bugs inexplicably caused by so much as an uninitialized value. (We're using the NDK.) Check again the glTexParameterf, it might have to be a glTexParameteri in java. About ruling things out: don't forget that different platforms run with different driver implementations. Would be a nice case to test all of them and compare.

Comment: If setting `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` causes rendering problems, that's suspicious. It means that you're relying on the default value of `GL_REPEAT` for correct rendering. As you already found, `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` is the only value that is guaranteed to be supported for NPOT textures. So you need to set it, and fix your code to work with it.

Comment: You're right @RetoKoradi and I think this may be the issue.  Not explicitly using GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE means that NPOT textures (which mine are) won't be displayed.  However, all other devices on which I've tested this including a *really* old mk1 Galaxy Ace, display everything fine!  I know that some devices have an extension of some description that allows extra wrap modes for NPOT textures, so I'm guessing even the Ace must have this extension!?  Anyhow, I have now sorted that issue and am now using GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE for both S & T :-)

Comment: Will return & accept answer once I've had a chance to test @StarShine